# Overlay 2x image blobs

Tags: javascript, canvas, png, blob

I've created a function that converts a Mapbox GL JS canvas to a png image blob.

```
map.getCanvas().toBlob(function (blob) {
    mapBlob=blob;
    saveAs(blob, 'map.png');
})
```

Unfortunatley this does not include DOM elements, one of which is the scalebar. I can create a seperate blob of the scalebar using [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image).

This looks like below and creates a perfectly sized image blob of the scalebar.

```
var node = document.getElementById('scaleBar');
domtoimage.toBlob(node)
  .then(function (blob) {
      scaleBlob=blob
      saveAs(scaleBlob, 'scale.png');
  })
```

After these two functions I have 2x image blobs that I'd like to combine (scale bar on top of map).

Using Javascript, how can I combine the now named variables scaleBlob and mapBlob to a single blob, which will then be saved as a png locally?

Examples of the saved map image
[image]

And saved scaled image (just a line really but sized appropriately)
[image]

And this is what I want as a new, final image
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var circle = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xml:space='preserve'  height='150' width='150'><circle cx='50' cy='50' r='20' stroke='black' stroke-width='3' fill='red' /></svg> ";
var blob1 = new Blob([circle], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});

var rect = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xml:space='preserve'  height='50' width='50'><rect width='30' height='50' style='fill:rgb(0,0,255)'/></svg> ";
var blob2 = new Blob([rect], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});

renderImage(blob1, 0, 0)
renderImage(blob2, 20, 50)

function renderImage(blob, x , y){
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){ ctx.drawImage(img, x, y) }
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
};
```

```html
<canvas id = 'canvas'></canvas>
```

Here I'm just putting the blobs from svg, but on the same way you could do with two different blobs, and at the end you can do the saveAs